# Running Maven Project from Jenkins does not pick up the pom.xml in the local directory

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm running Jenkins 1.529 on a Windows7 server, inside Apache Tomcat8.0, on JDK1.7.0_21.

When I run the mvn command for my project from the command line (in the root directory that contains the pom.xml where the project was checked out to) it runs fine.

But when I run from Jenkins, it doesn't seem to find the `pom.xml` on the `C:\.jenkins\workspace\<myProject>` location as it should, instead I see some message about downloading some pom.xml file from the internet.

I can't understand why it doesn't use the `pom.xml` file in the workspace directory.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured out what was going wrong.

Maven was taking the user settings from a different place when running from Jenkins, than when it was running from the command line.

I could see this line in the log files when running from Jenkins:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.1.0\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\.m2\settings.xml
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

And when I ran the mvn command from the command line I saw this:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin\..\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Users\<MyUserName>\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\<MyUserName>\.m2\repository
```

The issue was that I am behind a corporate firewall, so when run from Jenkins it could not download the dependencies. I had a settings.xml file in my `C:\Users\<MyUserName>\.m2` directory, which contained details for a proxy server to get around this.

I copied the settings.xml into `C:\.m2` directory and hey presto, it could now download the dependencies and build the project.

I guess the only question I have is as to why the Jenkins Maven Plugin does not use the same .m2 directory location as Maven does, but that is a seperate issue I now need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Jenkins uses the correct pom. The poms which gets downloaded are the ones of your dependencies (which are declared inside your own pom as you know). Most likely because Jenkins uses a different local Maven repository location than the command line client so it have to download everything again.

You can configure Jenkins which Maven installation should be used and where your local repository is located:

[image]

Comment: THanks for your help, you were right it was actually finding the correct pom.xml but could not download the dependencies due to the corporate firewall and the resolution was as I described in my answer.